# Django call command with parameters

Tags: django, python-2.7

I've a management command with the following argument parser section:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--out', action='store', dest='out', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('--todos', action='store', dest='todos', \
                required=True, nargs='+')
        parser.add_argument('--filter', action='store', dest='filter')
        parser.add_argument('--list', action='store', dest='list')
        parser.add_argument('--add_id', action='store_true', dest='add_id')
```

. I'm trying to call this command from a view / shell, but does not work:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('prg_name', out='/tmp/111.txt')
```

, however i got the following error: **argument --out is required** .

The program is kinda old:
python: 2.7
Django: 1.11.16

.

How should i call the call_command with parameters with this old layout?

What is strange, if i do this:

```
dt = {'--out=/tmp/111.txt': sth}
call_command(prg_name, *dt)
```

it works, however i can't define more value for --todos .

Comment: What is `sth` here?

Comment: Some random value. Just to make work the dictionary.

Comment: but here you perform *sequence unpacking* (there is only *one* asterisk `*`, not multiple ones), hence it will only look at the keys of the dictionaries, but you can pass a tuple, list, any iterable anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just pass an arbitrary number of strings to the command:

```
call_command(prg_name, '--out=/tmp/111.txt', '--todos', '8', '12', '105', '51')
```

You can see these as the parameters that you would have passed to your program if you called it from the command line.

Comment: Well, it solves the problem of --out, but for the --todos it takes only the latest one..

Comment: @user2194805: are you sure that is not because of the handling in your command itself. I would find it strange that the `call_command` itself is the problem since this basically just passes these, and are parsed by the argument parser: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/__init__.py#L147

Comment: @user2194805: what if you run the command from the command line?

Comment: It works fine from the command line: python manage.py create_document --out /tmp/444 --todos 8 12 105 51
{'add_id': False, 'settings': None, 'pythonpath': None, 'verbosity': 1, 'traceback': False, 'list': None, 'filter': None, 'no_color': False, 'todos': ['8', '12', '105', '51'], 'out': '/tmp/444'}

Comment: @user2194805: ah, but then you need to pass it like that as well.

Comment: But from the shell: In [25]: call_command('create_document', '--out=/tmp/zzz', '--todos=51', '--todos=105', '--todos=12', '--todos=8')
{'add_id': False, 'settings': None, 'pythonpath': None, 'verbosity': 1, 'traceback': False, 'list': None, 'filter': None, 'no_color': False, u'skip_checks': True, 'todos': [u'8'], 'out': u'/tmp/zzz'}

Comment: @user2194805: see edit. If you pass it like `--todos 8 4 2`, then these are four arguments: `--todos`, `8`, `4` and `2`.

Comment: I'd, but i got a ValueError for:call_command('create_document', '--out=/tmp/zzz', '--todos=8 12 105 51') --- ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8 12 105 51'

Comment: @user2194805: no, you need to pass these *separately*, so `'--todos', '8', '12'`, etc. see edit.

Comment: I should never do any coding if i'm tired. Thanks for your many helps... .